# Given the sum of this series, find the sum of another series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I've stumbled across this problem that asks, given this series whose sum is that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{{\pi^2}}{6}$$

Find the sum of this series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2} $$
The second function is just the odd function of the first function, however, I do not know where to proceed from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(2n)}^2=\frac14\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^2}.$$

Comment: I just came to this realization mere seconds before you posted this!

Comment: Great minds think together! ;o)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}= \sum \frac{1}{(2n)^2}+\sum \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}= \frac{1}{4}\sum \frac{1}{n^2}+\sum \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}$

Comment: Shouldn't the 1/2 be a 1/4?

Comment: Ooops , you are right !